# Blocking annoying cookie consent banner on Golem.de (if possible with the add-on ublock origin)

Tags: firefox, blocking, cookies, ublock-origin

I wish to block the annoying cookie consent banner on Golem.de. If possible with the add-on ublock origin.

I don't wish to install [i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/bru6wd/please_help_me_find_the_i_dont_care_about_cookies/) because there is no source repo. I use LibreWolf (Firefox build).

[image]

Link: [Golem.de](https://www.golem.de/sonstiges/zustimmung/auswahl.html?from=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.golem.de%2Fnews%2Fnach-musks-twitter-kauf-nextcloud-will-alle-nutzer-ins-mastodon-fediverse-bringen-2210-169319.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This consent dialog cannot be blocked because of how it is implemented: Unless you agree, the server sends a redirect to the dialog. The page with the dialog does not contain the article. The dialog does not rely on JavaScript.

Only when you consent does the server give out the actual article page. Even if you consent, your adblocker may still block all the trackers.

---

Personally, I simply stopped visiting Golem.de for pulling this stunt and I encourage everyone else do the same.